# How are different users' data separated in a single Parse.com application?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, parse-platform

How are data for different users separated in a single parse.com application in iOS? I am writing an application which will run on several different iPhones. How would the application differentiate between these different devices?

The application would have a single application ID. So would all of the data be stored under that ID?

I am not talking about push notifications. I am talking about differentiating between the users using my app. If all of the users’ data will be stored in my account, then how would I be able to differentiate between the users using my application?

Comment: `[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]` is a unique hardware identifier. You could use that to differentiate between devices, but not users :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to have User as a property on any parse objects you create. When you are querying you can specify the user identity. Here's some sample code:

```
PFQuery *query= [PFUser query];

[query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser]username]];

[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error){
    BOOL isPrivate = [[object objectForKey:@"isPrivate"]boolValue];
}];
```

Also, as mentioned by [@Hector Ramos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19617/hector-ramos), if the data is sensitive then you need to implement checks on the server end using ACL.

Comment: So do I have to ask each user to sign up on parse.com if they want to use my application?

Comment: Not at all .. If you have your own user management setup then you can use your userId as a property on parse objects. If you don't want user management at all then you can user parse Anonymous/Automatic users .. http://blog.parse.com/2012/04/02/protect-user-data-with-new-parse-features/

Answer (score 0):

When a user signs up to your Parse app, they get their own [PFUser](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#users/iOS) object. You can then use [ACLs](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#users-acls/iOS) to control access to each object on a per-user basis.

Answer (score -1):

You can't differentiate between the devices. When they are subscribed to the particular channel than all the devices will receive notification of that channel. You can't differentiate on the basic of device. You can do one thing create channels A and B . Subscribe the devices to the channel depending upon the requirement. then only those devices which are subscribed to the channel A or channel B will receive the notification of those channels.

Comment: I am not talking about push notifications.I am talking about differentiating between the users using my App.I was wondering if all data of all users would be stored in my account,then how would I be able to differentiate between the users using my application?

Comment: This is also completely false. The PFInstallation object has a globally unique identifier in its installationId field. This setting conforms to privacy standards because it is not the same across apps on the same device or across reinstallations of the same app.